# Pickle error in Pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, pickle

I am trying to parse xml in pyspark. I have a directory having many small xml files i want to parse all the xmls and put that in hdfs for that i have written below code.

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import pickle
filenme = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/root/CD")
dumpoff1 = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-put", "-", "/user/cloudera/Demo/Demo.txt"],stdin=PIPE)

def getname(filenm):
   return filenm[1]

def add_hk(filenm):
   source=[]
   global dumpoff1 
   doc = ET.fromstring(filenm)
   for elem1 in doc.findall('.//documentInfo/source'):
       source.append(elem1.text)
       print source[0]
       dumpoff1.stdin.write("%s\n" % source[0]) 

filenme.map(getname).foreach(add_hk)
```

but when i run this i am getting below error.

**Error:**

> File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.0-1.cdh5.11.0.p0.34/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
>   line 582, in save_file
>       raise pickle.PicklingError("Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading") pickle.PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that
>   are not opened for reading

i tried writing **Popen** inside **add_hk** then i am not getting the pickle error but the Demo.txt is getting overwritten and only have the latest files value. Please help.

Comment: Pickle error means you're returning a data type that is not handled by pyspark

Comment: `wholeTextFiles` writes file name at index `0` not `1` (in `getname`).

Comment: Could you provide some elements such as what your file looks like, are the paths local, what `add_hk`does

Comment: @Marie i cannot share the files as it is confidential. `add_hk` takes the contents of the xml files and returns.

Comment: @Marie i want the contents of the file, as my file is present in hdfs i cannot pass the file path to the function as it works only in local path.

Comment: Why don't you use the spark sql function?

Comment: It's no problem. A lot of (most?) structured data formats are handled by spark sql if not you can always load your data as RDDs using `sc.textFile()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153617/discussion-between-ironman-and-marie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load your `xml`files using spark SQL and then write them in hdfs:

Assuming `/user/root/CD/` is a local path (otherwise remove the `file://`):

```
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='page').load('file:///user/root/CD/*')
```

you can write it as `parquet`:

```
df.write.parquet([HDFS path])
```

Comment: since my files are in hdfs do i have to change `load('file:///user/root/CD/*')` statement ?

Comment: yes you do :) and you should modify rowTag to fit your data